# How do I determine the size of a dynamically allocated structure in Java before writing it to a file?

Tags: java, dynamic, size, structure

Say, for example, I have a complex dynamically allocated structure (such as a binary tree) that needs to be written to a file made up of different sections. I would like to first write the size of the structure as a dword followed by the structure itself, however the size of the structure is only known after I have written the structure to the file. It is difficult, in this case, to pre-determine the size of the structure in memory.

Is it best to write the size as 0, then write the structure, then seek back and overwrite the size with the correct value? I don't like that idea, though. Is there a better/proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: write the data to a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), after that, you should be able to call `size()` to get the actual length in bytes and call `toByteArray()` to get the byte buffer, that can be written to a file.

---

*Code example*

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
  objects.add("Hello World");
  objects.add(new Double(42.0));
  System.out.println(sizeof(objects));               
}

public static int sizeof(Serializable object) {
  ObjectOutputStream out = null;
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
  try {
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    out.writeObject(object);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (out != null) {
      try {
        out.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  return baos != null? baos.size() : -1;
}
```

This just demonstrate a *sizeof emulator* (which is different from the c implementation, because it calculates the size of a *serialized* object - the implementation for *raw* bytes would be slightly different).

Comment: This was an option I considered, however the fact that it buffers the data in memory is duplicating the data that I already have in memory (even if it is only temporary). What if the data structure was very large? I don't want this operation to hog a lot of memory.

Comment: @Dean - you'll duplicate parts of it anyway - no one really writes single bytes to a file, we always use buffered streams. But as we don't have (and need) a `sizeof` operator in Java, I see no other solution.

Comment: @Andreas_D, I doubt the Instrumention.getSizeOf() would return a number which is exactly the same as how you would write data to disk. A simple `sizeof` implementation would give you the size in memory including object header and padding.

Comment: So first I have the data structure in memory. It takes up, say, 200MB of memory. I then write the data to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which takes up another 200MB of memory. A call to `toByteArray()` creates a copy of the data; another 200MB of memory. That's an additional 400MB of memory that was needed just to pre-determine the size of the structure before I write it to the file. Still, this is probably the most elegent way.

Comment: @Peter - have a look at my example, that calculates the size of a *serialized* datastructure. Calculating *raw* bytes would make use of the same BAOS, but the sizeof method wouldn't be as easy and short - it would depend on the *real* datastructure that has to be written. Anyway - BAOS has the methods, that we could use, to calculate sizes of datastructures.

Comment: I think using `ByteArrayOutputStream` is the best option. I probably don't need `toByteArray()`, I can just use `writeTo(...)` to write it to the file directly without creating an intermediate byte array.

Comment: @Andreas_D, ObjectOutputStream can be surprisingly inefficient e.g. your `sizeof((byte) 1)` returns `75`. Perhaps if we are going to the trouble of writing a mini DBMS we can do better than that. ;)

Comment: @Peter - yes, but look above the line: BAOS was the actual friend, OOS was just added to provide some sample codes with a reasonable number of lines

Comment: @Andreas_D, +1 You are correct there. This approach can be used even if you compress the stream or use another serialisation strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you looked at [Random Access Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) yet?

Comment: So you're saying I should write the size as 0, then write the structure, then seek back and overwrite the size with the correct value using a random access file?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to write the size at all?  Won't the file be the size of the structure after you have written it?

If you have variable components like arrays or lists, you can write the sizes of those as you write the data.  However the total length is redundant and not very useful.

If you really have to, you can write the data to a ByteArrayOutputStream first to get the length. (But I seriously doubt it)

Comment: "Won't the file be the size of the structure after you have written it?" No, because the file is made up of different sections. The data structure is just one section.

Comment: @Dean, Ok, can you say what you are going to use the length for when reading the data back? IS it so you can skip through the file?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I want to be able to read parts of the file non-linearly. To do this I suspect I will need a file header containing offsets to the different sections, but how would I determine the offsets when I don't know the sizes of the sections before they are written to the file?

Comment: You could do what JAR/ZIP format does and write the index/name/length/offset table at the end of the file. The advantage of this is that all the information is in one place (making disk access faster) and you only need to keep in memory the index information (rather than keeping in memory the largest structure)  You could even use JAR/ZIP format for your file.  If your structures are large they may compress well could speed up disk access (by reducing the amount of data you need to read) And it saves you having to invent a disk structure of your own.

Comment: @Dean sounds like you want some kind of DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below url http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=83 for calculating size of object .This utility seems worthful for your need.

To measure the size of a particular object containing data,  measure JVM memory use before and after building the object.